# Unable to resolve errors from StickyListHeaders

Tags: android

I want to run a sample project of [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) in Eclipse. For that I copy-pasted all their classes,layouts,etc. into my project but into that code many errors are generated !

As the code is so large & there are so much errors that I don't feel like questioning here.

And I don't find any tutorial like it on google & also in SO, the questions about StickyListHeaders are subjected to some/other problem.

Anyone can provide me a demo app (tutorial) implementing StickyListHeaders that runs.

Sorry, If my question doesn't show any research effort or If you think that I am forcing someone to do some work !

Thanks..

Comment: You got to post the errors so that we can help you. I have used this `ListView` so many times without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use below code to achieve StickyListHeaders,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
     ListView list; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));        
        list.setOnScrollListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {     
        //the listview has only few children (of course according to the height of each child) who are visible
        for(int i=0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = list.getChildAt(i);
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) child.getTag();

            //if the view is the first item at the top we will do some processing
            if(i == 0){             
                boolean isAtBottom = child.getHeight() <= holder.header.getBottom();
                int offset = holder.previousTop - child.getTop();
                if(!(isAtBottom && offset > 0)){                    
                    holder.previousTop = child.getTop();
                    holder.header.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);                   
                    holder.header.invalidate();
                }
            } //if the view is not the first item it "may" need some correction because of view re-use
            else if (holder.header.getTop() != 0) {
                int offset = -1 * holder.header.getTop(); 
                holder.header.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
                holder.previousTop = 0;
                holder.header.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    private static class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public Adapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.header);
            for(int i=0; i < 50; i++){
                add(Integer.toString(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
                convertView.setTag(holder);             
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.header.setText(getItem(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView header;
        int previousTop = 0;
    }


}
```

As you can see above android's `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` interface is used by implementing its  `onScroll()` to listen  the scrolling of the list.`onScroll()`will be called after the scroll has completed.There is an adapter which uses `ViewHolder` to store the `header view` and also a variable `previousTop` to keep track of the change in the scroll for each successive scroll events .This is because of the fact that `offsetTopAndBottom()` changes offset of the view related to the previous location of it.

Coming to the `Adapter` class, `add(Integer.toString(i));` is used just to add integer values to an `ArrayList` which in turn used to show as a header. As a result you can see 50 headers in the `ListView`. `void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(String object)`
 Adds the specified object at the end of the array.

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The xml below contains a `TextView` which is for Header and an `ImageView` which is for the content part.You can use any view for it as per your need.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="#aaaaff" 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Deneme Row"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:background="#99ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code is pretty self explanatory.Still if you need any explanation, I will explain.

You can also refer the following,

http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/instagram-list-view/

https://bitbucket.org/ashish2py/instagramheader/downloads

**Note**: *I have copied this code from somewhere I don't remember. If anyone can provide me the link to this code, I will add the reference here.Sorry for not giving the credit to the original author.*

Comment: Your code is running fine ! Thanks ! Can u pls explain me the use of line `add(Integer.toString(i));` & method onScroll() in more detail

Comment: also `child` `previoustop`

Comment: I will accept ur answer if you explain my above queries

Comment: @Warde: I am sorry buddy, I wasn't on PC since many days.I have updated some explanation.Hope it clears your doubt.